# Render Blender model on a server

Tags: blender

We are using Blender to open a .blend model, apply some python code via the python console and create a .dae file.

Now we need to implement this functionality on a linux server to serve .dae files to a browser on request.

That means we (conceptually) need to trigger blender from the console, pass the .blend-file and the python script as arguments and make blender to output the .dae file.

We are not blender experts, so maybe you can tell me a) whether this is possible without starting the blender GUI and doing it manually or not and b) what options we have to achieve that functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender is quite flexible. You can run it on a server without the GUI (in background mode) and also execute a python script within blender to manipulate the scene (e.g. export .DAE):

```
./blender --background --python yourExportDAEScript.py
```

More command line options available in [the manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Command_Line)

yourExportDAEScript.py could manipulate the model and finally do something like:

```
bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath="/DAE/EXPORT/PATH/file.dae")
```

More details in the [Blender Python API](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_66_6/contents.html)